# Using TemplateUrl doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, routes

Hello i have a problem with my code. When i click on link page isn`t reload.

Here is a HTML and JS code:

```js
var app=angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
          .when('/',{
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
          })
          .when('/about',{
                templateUrl: 'about.html'
          });
    .when('/contact',{
                templateUrl: 'contact.html'
          });
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
});
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
 
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/about">About us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
   <br/>
    <div ng-view >
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Have you any idea what`s wrong?

Comment: You are trying to `.when` off a delimiter `;`

Comment: remove semicolon after when()

Comment: if i delete ; before .when nothing is change

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var app=angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
          $routeProvider
              .when('/',{
                    templateUrl: 'home.html'
              })
              .when('/about',{
                    templateUrl: 'about.html'
              })
              .when('/contact',{
                    templateUrl: 'contact.html'
              })
              .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    });
    app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){

    });
```

Comment: Pages in adress is changing but in my ng-view is nothing happens. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon (;) for second and thirs .when cases

```
var app=angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .when('/about',{
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
      })
      .when('/contact',{
            templateUrl: 'contact.html'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the console. Probably your BASE tag is missing. Add it to the HEAD tag.

```
<base href="/" />
```